# How can I run this setState function for say every 1 sec

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
void play(){    
setState(() {
  tween = new VibesTween(
    tween.evaluate(animation),
    new Wave.random(size, random),
  );
  animation.forward(from: 0.0);
});
}
```

I need to call this play function which animates a particular animation. The only problem is it runs every time I click a button. I need it to call state every 1 second and rerender the animation again for every second. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to call `setState` every second, you just need a repeating animation. And [`AnimationController`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) has a [`repeat`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController/repeat.html) method for cases like this.

To set it off in its most basic form you can just call,

```
animationController.repeat();
```

But you can also provide overrides, as in

```
animationController.repeat(min: 0.0, max: 1.0, period: Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Comment: I answered like this because they specifically asked how to run "this setState function [...] every [..] sec[ond]". I am also not seeing the use case in it. I like your answer and think that mine is appropriate in this case as well.

Comment: Yeah repeat is a specific use case. Using status listener covers a broader range of scenarios. I only pointed this out because in my experience `repeat` saves on rebuilds, compared to calling `animationController.forward` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You may call the `play()` method every one second by passing it as a Callback function parameter in `Timer.Periodic(Duration, Callback)` method.

```
const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) -> play());
```